# Identify windows command output uniquely for first execution

Tags: command-line, command, command-prompt

I am executing command on 1 hr interval daily from a third party tool.
I have an requirement to identify that the command is executing for first time.
as if its executing first time i need to go to task 'A' if not then task 'B'

e.g.
command:

> net start

outputs

> First Execution

[some flag to identify as this is first output]

test

> Next Execution

test

so in this case, i could be able to identify if its First execution or not.

Comment: i need that in a single line command

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: mainline - test first/not first

CALL :testfirst ###
IF DEFINED alreadyrun (ECHO ### already run) ELSE (ECHO ### first run)
CALL :testfirst $$$
IF DEFINED alreadyrun (ECHO $$$ already run) ELSE (ECHO $$$ first run)
CALL :testfirst ###
IF DEFINED alreadyrun (ECHO ### already run) ELSE (ECHO ### first run)
CALL :testfirst $$$
IF DEFINED alreadyrun (ECHO $$$ already run) ELSE (ECHO $$$ first run)

GOTO :eof


:testfirst
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
SET "alreadyrun=%date:/=-%"
IF EXIST "%targetdir%\%alreadyrun%.%1" GOTO :eof
DEL "%targetdir%\*.%1" 2>NUL >nul
echo,>"%targetdir%\%alreadyrun%.%1"
SET "alreadyrun=" 

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances. `U:\destdir` suits my system.

The idea here is to establish a special directory in which to keep relevant data. I chose `u:\destdir` as that is convenient for me. `%temp%` or `%tmp%` may be an obvious choice, but these can be arbitrarily cleared at any time, so are probably not the best.

The mainline portion shows two different procedures being "run" called `###` and `$$$` - the names are not important and can be almost anything you like. The critical portion is the `:testfirst` subroutine (which I've written as an internal subroutine, but could be an independent batch file if you prefer - just change the `call :testfirst` to `call testfirst`)

This routine sets the variable `alreadyrun` to the current date with the `/` characters transformed to `-` as `/` is not a valid filename character.

Then see whether the file (transformed date).%1 exists in the selected directory (where %1 is replaced by the argument provided - `###` and `$$$` in the example). If it does, simply terminate the routine and return with `alreadyrun` set to a value.

If the file does not exist, delete any files with the same `###` extension from the directory (they were created yesterday or before) and create a new (today).### file. Then delete the environment variable `alreadyrun`.

The calling routing will then see `alreayrun` as being undefined (not already run) or defined (already been run today) which should fulfill your need.